# Disk Appears as Dynamic Unreadable in Disk Management

Tags: dynamic-disk

I have 2 hard disks in my system, both Hitachi. I formatted the 160 GB HDD but now its showing other (1 TB HDD) as "Dynamic disk" and data is unaccessible. Partitions are not being shown either. I don't to convert it because that will erase the data. It had ~800 GB data. What to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once used the approach described here

[Convert Dynamic Disk back to Basic Disk without data loss](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=191006)

The idea is to modify MBR, to more precise partition's identified aka descriptor.
But, prior to making changes I would try it on a test drive.

Comment: Hey thanks, I'll try that. What do you mean try on a test drive?

Comment: Well, before doing this on production machine, first of all I went through the entire process on a test virtual machine which had dynamic volume. 

Just be very careful while editing MBR. If questions appear, you can post them back here.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I'll arrange VMware and test it first. I really can't afford to loose that data :'(

Comment: Hey,I forgot to metion this, but I am getting another option - "import foreign disks". Will it erase delete partitions or delete data? Screenshot - http://prntscr.com/jhqio

Comment: There should be no problems with importing foreign disks according to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738101(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_FOREIGN)

Comment: Hey,thanks for the reply, so I clicked on import and here's the screenshot - http://prntscr.com/jhsrb Should I click okay? Will it damage the data?

Comment: Proceed with OK. No, it shouldn't harm it.

Comment: Woah! It worked! Thanks brother, finally I did it :D Thank you very much :)

Comment: Cool, you r welcome! :)